# Nodejs AWS S3 createPresignedPost returns error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have the following code:

```
const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { createPresignedPost } = require('@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post');

router.post(
  '/sign-s3', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { name, type } = req.body;
    const client = new S3Client({
      region: 'eu-central-1',
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      },
    });
    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Expires: 60,
      Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', 100, 5242880],
        { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
      ],
      Fields: {
        key: `blog/${name}`,
        'Content-Type': type,
        success_action_status: '201',
      },
    };
    try {
      const data = await createPresignedPost(client, params);
      return res.json(data);
    } catch (err) {
      return next({ status: 500, message: err.message });
    }
  }
);
```

This route returns the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')
```

This error is not very helpful. I tried passing credentials directly into the S3Client object configuration because I had issues with V2 SDK not reading the credentials from .env automatically (the docs claim it should) but that didn't help. I ran these params with V2 and it worked just fine so I'm sure they're not the problem here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I've figured it out so I'm going to answer my own question in case anyone Googles this.

The problem was that I passed `key` inside `Fields`. Doing so is fine for [AWS js SDK v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) but not so for [AWS js SDK v3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3). Where v3 `createPresignedPost` expects `Key` to be passed directly, like so:

```js
const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Expires: 60,
    Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', 100, 5242880],
        { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
    ],
    Fields: {
        'Content-Type': type,
        success_action_status: '201',
    },
    Key: '${name}',
};
```

I did try passing only `Bucket` to `createPresignedPost` while trying out different approaches. Apparently, you don't get a proper error if you don't include `Key` and it's required.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I was googling it as you suspected haha